# How to add date validation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

This is my form that I use to post data. All of it works just fine in terms of inputting. This is just for reference to my javascript validation form.

```
<form action= "<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post" name="input" id="input">
            <br>
            <table>
              <tr>
                <th>Animal Name</th>
                <td><input type="text" name="ANM_NAME" id="ANM_NAME" maxlength="20"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Owner Name</th>
                <td><input type="text" name="OWN_NAME" id="OWN_NAME" maxlength="20"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Sign in</th>
                <td><input type="date" name="SIGN_IN" id="SIGN_IN"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Medication</th>
                <td><input type="text" name="MEDS" id="MEDS" maxlength="20"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Special Requirements</th>
                <td><input type="text" name="SPEC" id="SPEC" maxlength="20"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Food</th>
                <td><input type="text" name="FOOD" id="FOOD" maxlength="20"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Notes</th>
                <td><input type="text" name="NOTE" id="NOTE" maxlength="20"></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
            <br>
        <input type="button" id="button" value="Submit">
      </form>
```

Currently I have this for validation, on the button click it sets the var flag to true and then checks input type text to see if they have text, if they do it submits, if not it creates pop-up alert.

```
  <!-- Checking if inputs are entered-->
  <script>
  $("#button").click(function(){
    var flag=true;

    // check all input values
    $("input[type='text']").each(function(){
        if( $(this).val()=="" ){
            flag=false;
        }
    });

    // submit the form
    if(flag){
        $("form#input").submit()
    }else{
        // You should do something here.
        alert("Please fill all inputs!");
    }
  });
  </script>
```

But it does not work for the date as it is using a different input type. How would I add the date input to this validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select more then one type of input using a delimiter:

```
<script>
  $("#button").click(function() {
    var flag = true;

    // check all input values
    $("input[type='text'],input[type='date']").each(function() {
      if ($(this).val() == "") {
        flag = false;
      }
    });

    // submit the form
    if (flag) {
      $("form#input").submit()
    } else {
      // You should do something here.
      alert("Please fill all inputs!");
    }
  });
</script>
```